# How to write a List of ArrayLists to CSV format in Java

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, casting

I have data in the below format:

```
   List<ArrayList<String>>
```

I want to write it to CSV. Below is my code:

```
private static void writeToCSV(List<ArrayList<String>> csvInput) throws IOException{

String csv = "C:\\output.csv";
CSVWriter writer = null;

try {
    writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

for(ArrayList<String> each: csvInput){
    writer.writeNext(each);
}


writer.close();
}//end of writeTOCSV
```

The method 'writeNext' allows only String[ ] as it's argument. When I try to type cast 'ArrayList each' into String[] using an Object[ ] as shown below, I am getting run time type casting error:

```
   Object[] eachTemp = each.toArray();
   writer.writeNext((String[]) eachTemp);
```

Could anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast `Object[]` into `String[]` because `Object[]` can contains Dog, Cat, Integer etc.

you should use overloaded [List#toArray(T[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29) method.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[] {});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do `new String[list.size()]`?

Comment: @All The problem with this is that two arrays are needed.

Comment: @Danny yes also correct or use `list.toArray(new String[0]);`

Comment: @Braj Any array shorter than the size of the list is discarded and a new one is created.

Answer (score 2):

You are converting your list to array of objects. To create array of strings do:

```
for(ArrayList<String> each: csvInput){
    writer.writeNext(each.toArray(new String[each.size()]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out using the parameterized version of `toArray` instead -

```
    String[] eachTemp = each.toArray(new String[each.size()]);
    writer.writeNext(eachTemp);
```

edit: oops they beat me to it!